# Querying for multiple rows in a table (and its pair in the same table) where one half of the pair is connected to one id in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a random question that I am trying to figure out in SQL.

Say you have a table whereby the rows come in pairs. So you will have:

```
same_table
ID Name Family_Id Other_id
1   B.       1.       2 --> This ID is id 2 in the same table.
2.  C.       nil      nil
3   D.       1        4 --> this ID is also the next row in the table.
4   E.       nil      nil
```

Sorry, this is incredibly convoluted and hard to explain. Essentially I need to get the rows connected to family_id 1 AND the other part of the pair.

So I know `SELECT * FROM same_table WHERE family_id=1` --> will get 1 half.

HOW do I write a query where I am looking specifically for the rows connected to a specific family_id and that rows pair.

Sorry... poorly explained but I don't know how else to ask it.

Comment: In the case above, do you still need four rows to be returned, of would it be more appropriate to return two rows?  Such as `B, C` as one rows and `D, E` as a second row?

Comment: each row relates to an object and I need all 4 objects if that makes sense?

Comment: You can still get both objects' full information in a single row...  `ID, Name, FamilyID, OtherID, OtherName`  In the one row the `ID, Name` describe the parent row and the `OtherID, OtherName` describe the child row *(or contain NULLs if there is no child)*.  Then, it's just a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Sorry still fairly new. So essentially, I would want to find both and store them in a variable that has all of them as separate objects in the variable. So when I call that variable I have all those rows? If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the hierarchy is only one level deep (as in your example data and explanation), you can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from same_table t
where t.family_id = :input or
      exists (select 1
              from same_table t2
              where t2.other_id = t.id and t2.famil_id = :input
             );
```

Comment: yep, literally looking for all rows related to a single family_id AND that row's partner in the same table. Thanks for your response, I shall try it out... also if you understood what I was asking, is there a better way for me to explain it / ask it haha.

Comment: Hi there, can you explain the select 1 after exists. Is that 1 meant to be the same as t.family_id= 1 in the line above??

Comment: @Tigiras . . . the `1` in `SELECT 1` is a syntactic convenience, because `exists` only checks whether *rows* are returned (not what is in the row).  I updated the answer to clarify this.